# move up UIAlertController style Alert with UITextView when keyboard is present

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview, uialertview

i have an AlertController with UITextView.

when UITexView become first responder the alter doesn't move up with the keyboard.

this is my code:

```
@IBAction func showAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, I'm alert! \n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let rect        =   CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 240, height: 150)//CGRectMake(15, 50, 240, 150.0)
    let textView    = UITextView(frame: rect)

    textView.font               = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)
    textView.textColor          = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.white
    textView.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth  = 1.0
    textView.text               = "Enter message here"
    textView.delegate           = self

    alertController.view.addSubview(textView)

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { action in

        let msg = (textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray) ? "" : textView.text

        print(msg!)

    })
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.addAction(action)


    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {

        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
}
```

and this is my result:

[image]
there is a solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

just addTextField and then remove it

```
    alert.addTextField { field in
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        field.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    let inCntrlr =  alert.childViewControllers[0].view!
    inCntrlr.removeFromSuperview()
```

and then you could add your own views. here is a
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkHPh.png)

Comment: Works perfectly on 4.2. Very easy to implement.

Comment: This really lacks more information :/ Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Edit: this works but for some reason you have to put it at the end of alert controller construction, after you add all the views. Making it at the beginning for me caused the app to crash.

Comment: This works, but it would be good to know, why it works :)

Answer (score 2):

After presenting alert controller. Open keyboard for TextView and move alert controller up.
I hope this will suite for you.

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        alertController.view.frame.origin.y = 100
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` by default will slide up when they keyboard is shown. The problem here is that you have added a subview to the alert controller. From the [UIAlertController docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller):

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Adding your own subview to the alert goes against what the docs say and is likely what is causing your problem. If you need an alert with a text view in it, your best bet is to create your own view and manage it yourself.

Comment: @ keithbhunter are right. Alternatively, you can use text field by`func addTextField(configurationHandler: ((UITextField) -> Void)? = nil)`. That one is managed by UIAlertViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I created this drop-in replacement, also customizable for any special needs of course. It's pretty simple and 'just works'!

https://gist.github.com/unixb0y/42a1ae0fb707bdb5e1e484bafd33d44a

It is a subclass of *UIAlertController* with a *UITextView* inside.

When it is initialized, it observes keyboard changes and adjusts its *view.frame.origin.y* accordingly.

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 100 {
    didSet {
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let menu = self.view.frame.height
        let keyb = self.keyboardHeight
        self.view.frame.origin.y = height-menu-keyb-20
    }
}

...
...
...

@objc func keyboardChange(sender: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = sender.userInfo else { return }
    let endFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
    keyboardHeight = endFrame?.height ?? 100
}
```

Comment: This works well, though orientation changes to get in the way a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's like. You open keyboard and change alert position.

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
var alertControllerPositon:CGFloat = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@IBAction func showAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, I'm alert! \n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

let rect        =   CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 240, height: 150)//CGRectMake(15, 50, 240, 150.0)
let textView    = UITextView(frame: rect)

textView.font               = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)
textView.textColor          = UIColor.lightGray
textView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.white
textView.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
textView.layer.borderWidth  = 1.0
textView.text               = "Enter message here"
textView.delegate           = self

alertController.view.addSubview(textView)

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { action in

    let msg = (textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray) ? "" : textView.text

    print(msg!)

})
alertController.addAction(cancel)
alertController.addAction(action)


self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {

    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
})
alertControllerPositon = alertController.view.frame.origin.y
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        alertControllerPositon = alertController.view.frame.origin.y
        let result = self.view.frame.height - (alertController.view.frame.height + alertController.view.frame.origin.y) - 20
        self.alertController.view.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize.height - result)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.alertController.view.frame.origin.y != alertControllerPositon  {
        self.alertController.view.frame.origin.y = alertControllerPositon
    }
}
```